# play audio with controls in iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, audio, controls, audio-streaming

I'm building an App that plays a mp3 file (hosted on `http://<somewhere>/<audio>.mp3`) while the user is watching some changing labels (think about a lyrics app, which write the lyrics synchronised with the song).

In the bottom side of the screen I'd like to show the audio controls (play/pause, ff, rew), and a bar for indicating the downloaded part of the file and the playing point.

How is the easiest way to do it? I've already tried with AVAudioPlayer, AVplayer and MPMoviePlayerController, but none of them solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use MPVolumeView Class.Read the documentation here http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/mediaplayer/reference/MPVolumeView_Class/Reference/Reference.html